# Zoom to full screen?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

How to activate/use this feature in D2010 ?!?

I have checked `Zoom to full screen` in `Tools > Option > Editor Option > Display` clicked `Ok` button but nothing happened. Ok, i said to myself, let's see what the help has to say about this. I pressed F1 key, wait a little, help's coming up but as i have expected, it has no idea about this, ironically: the help didn't help. Google did find some old blog posts which provided some outdated information like `double click on the editor tab` or `pressing F5` will do the thick. But, that's not the case, so i'm asking here maybe somebody has more information about this.

Answer (score 1):

That option controls whether the code editor, *when zoomed*, will zoom to occupy the entire screen. If that option isn't set, then maximizing the edit window will leave space at the top of the screen for the main IDE application window. If you never maximize the editor window, then that setting has no effect. It might also only have an effect when you're using the "classic undocked" layout mode.